# How can I add file/folder completion to fish shell for a git command?

Tags: git, autocomplete, fish

I'm using fish shell 3.1.0.

When I type `git difftool` and hit tab, it gives me a list of local branches, remote branches, HEAD, and ORIG_HEAD, but it does NOT give me a list of files and directories in the current working directory.

I very, very frequently run a command like `git difftool SOME_DIR`, or `git difftool SOME_FILE`, to see what changes I have made in that dir, or that file since the last commit. This missing autocompletion means that I have to type out the full name of SOME_DIR or SOME_FILE every time.

Is there a way to fix this by somehow adding file/folder completion to fish's completion of `git difftool`?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```sh
complete -c git -n '__fish_seen_subcommand_from difftool' -a '(__fish_complete_path)'
```

As for saving this permanently, putting this single line in `~/.config/fish/completions/git.fish` will disable all other completions for git. So you'll have to source the default completions first:

```sh
# ~/.config/fish/completions/git.fish
source $__fish_data_dir/completions/git.fish
complete -c git -n '__fish_seen_subcommand_from difftool' -a '(__fish_complete_path)'
```

Also, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (bound to `__fish_list_current_token`) will list the directory contents of the token under the cursor if it is a directory, otherwise the contents of the current directory which can be useful if the normal completions of `git difftool` are a screenfull and you want to take a quick peek at the files.

Comment: I finally got around to testing this. It didn't seem to help. Neither the temporary command, nor adding `git.fish` fixed the issue. After modifying `git.fish`, I disconnected from my remote server (SSH), and reconnected, effectively re-running fish, which should have re-read that file. Didn't help. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Completion files are initially not loaded, they are read once you hit tab after a command and cached thereafter. But if the completions are not working at all, I'm not sure what the problem could be :/